# Use JSON data to assign scope variables in controller, not view

Tags: json, angularjs

My application receives a JSON object with two boolean values. I am accessing the JSON data in my controller using the following:

```
$http.post('url-here', {"token": token })
        .success(function(data) {$scope.tokenValidate = data;});
```

This is the JSON object I receive:

```
{valid: true, expired: false}
```

I am able to access this data within my view using the following:

```
{{ tokenValidate.valid }} or {{ tokenValidate.expired }}
```

Instead, because of the way I'm creating my view, I'd like to use these boolean values to assign strings to scope variables from within the controller, like this:

```
if ($scope.tokenValidate.valid) {
    $scope.header = "Choose a new password";
} else if ($scope.tokenValidate.expired) {
    $scope.header = "This link has expired.";
    $scope.mesage = "Enter your email address to receive a new link."
} else {
    $scope.header = "This link is invalid."
}
```

When I do this, the controller fails to read the JSON data correctly.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

Any help? My guess is that it has something to with the fact that when I access the JSON from the view, it has already been loaded, but when I try to access it from the controller, `$scope.tokenValidate` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: what do you mean by fails to read JSON data correctly ?? any details of or error or any example of error ?

Comment: there will be some error in console

Comment: Are you handling above if else conditions in success callback of $http ?
and `$scope.tokenValidate.valid` and `$scope.tokenValidate.expired` gives Boolean or string ?

Comment: Yes, the if/else is after the $http in the code, and I've tested those variables to see if they are strings - they're simply not there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the values are strings, not bool

```
if ($scope.tokenValidate.valid=='true') {
    $scope.header = "Choose a new password";
} else if ($scope.tokenValidate.expired=='true') {
    $scope.header = "This link has expired.";
    $scope.mesage = "Enter your email address to receive a new link."
} else {
    $scope.header = "This link is invalid."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use returned json data, first parse it and then use it.

```
$http.post('url-here', {"token": token })
    .then(function(data) {
     var data=JSON.parse(data);
   if (data.valid) {
       $scope.header = "Choose a new password";
   } else if (data.expired) {
      $scope.header = "This link has expired.";
      $scope.mesage = "Enter your email address to receive a new link."
   } else {
     $scope.header = "This link is invalid."
   }    

  });
```